# Using SELECT for simple BOOLEAN evaluation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to test some evaluations without working on any table.
For example, you can write

```
SELECT 1+1
>2
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT 2 > 1
>FALSE
```

I know that most engines don't have the concept of a boolean data type, but I don't know how their internal work (even if I guess everything <> 0 is `true`, like in C). Anyway, the format of the response really doesn't matter, whether it's `true/false` or `0/1`

Comment: Oh how much I wish SQL had an actual boolean type...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 > 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN 2 > 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 > 1 THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE cast(1 as bit) END
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

SQL Server 2012 (Denali):

```
SELECT IIF(2 > 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```

Comment: I'd like this solution a lot, but it doesn't seem to work on my SQL server 2008

Comment: My fault, it's from 2012 :-/, I've been reading about it yesterday ([Denali – Logical Function – IIF() – A Quick Introduction](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/10/sql-server-denali-logical-function-iif-a-quick-introduction/)) and I've forget the version.

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql and Oracle and apparently SQL-Server you can use `nullif` (ignore the `from dual` for SQL-Server) so, assuming you take null as true then you can deal with equality testing this way without a messy case statement or having to deal with strings.

```
SQL> select nullif(1,0) from dual;

NULLIF(1,0)
-----------
          1

SQL> select nullif(1,1) from dual;

NULLIF(1,1)
-----------

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
SELECT expr1 condition expr2
```

Eg.

```
SELECT 1 < 2 # returns 1
```

Returns 1 if condition evaluates to true, 0 otherwise.

Tested successfully on:

- MariaDB 10.1
- MySQL 5.7 (Percona XtraDB Cluster)